# RemoveAt() should not delete values in multiple C#-lists

Tags: c#

I created a program with multiple classes and multiple lists in each class.
In the following you'll find a code example:

```
RsiClass rsi = new RsiClass();
RSI = await rsi.RsiDrawGraph(valueList);
```

The function rsi.RsiDrawGraph() (in my child class) changes the values in the list:

```
public async Task<List<RsiModel>> RsiDrawGraph(List<ChartDataModel> allValue)
{
    List<RsiModel> returnValues = new List<RsiModel>();
    for (int i= allValue.Count - 1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        returnValues.Add(new RsiModel { LowerBorder = 30, UpperBorder = 70, rsi = await Rsi(allValue), Time = allValue[i].Time, x=allValue[i].x });
        allValue.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    return returnValues;
}
```

Finally, the function returns the expected results but the values in my other "valueList" also changed too. In detail, it seems that the removeAt() command effected my other valueList in the main class, because the valueList is empty after the operation.

Why does it happened and how can I prevent, that the childclass is effecting my list in the main class?

Comment: Sounds like you're passing around references to the same list when your intention is to pass copies of its value.

Comment: Thank you! And how can I prevent this?

Comment: You'll need to at least post enough code for a reproducible example to get help. How is `allValue` passed to `RsiDrawGraph`? What else uses it?

Comment: Why are you removing values from your list param, if you don't want to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the caller of `RsiDrawGraph` does not expect you to modify `allValue` you can do something like this:

```
public async Task<List<RsiModel>> RsiDrawGraph(IEnumerable<ChartDataModel> allValue)
{
    List<ChartDataModel> chartData = new List<ChartDataModel>(allValue);
    List<RsiModel> returnValues = new List<RsiModel>();
    for (int i = chartData.Count - 1; i > = 0; i--)
    {
        returnValues.Add(new RsiModel { LowerBorder = 30, UpperBorder = 70, rsi = await Rsi(chartData), Time = chartData[i].Time, x=chartData[i].x });
        chartData.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    return returnValues;
}
```

This way, you're modifying a copy of `allValue` that is local to the method so you avoid unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can not delete from a collection while iterating over it. you should make a copy of it by using .ToList(). Moreover, list of objects is passed by reference in the function parameter. That's why your other "valueList" also have same effect as allValue. Here allValue & valueList is pointing to the same memory location. make a copy of allValue so that valueList won't change

```
public async Task<List<RsiModel>> RsiDrawGraph(List<ChartDataModel> allValue)
{
    List<ChartDataModel> allValueCopy = allValue.ToList();
    List<RsiModel> returnValues = new List<RsiModel>();
    for (int i= allValueCopy.Count - 1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        returnValues.Add(new RsiModel { LowerBorder = 30, UpperBorder = 70, rsi = await Rsi(allValueCopy), Time = allValueCopy[i].Time, x=allValueCopy[i].x });
        allValueCopy.RemoveAt(i);
    }
    return returnValues;
}
```

Comment: No need to do ToList() ToArray() is enough, and has a smaller footprint... and yes, be aware of the references being shared. And if you do not want to impact the original list, why removing the found items in the first place?

Comment: @Hans-HenrikMøller he's passing the smaller list to the `rsi` property of the new `RsiModel` in each iteration of the loop

Comment: @HasaniH.. no.. he is passing the copy of the original list.. but as that code is not supplied, then I assumed it was not important....

Comment: @Hans-HenrikMøller he was also removing an item from the original list at each iteration, the root of his problem, hence passing a smaller list each time...

Answer (score 0):

You use `allValue` list in `for` loop and you can't remove items in list when you use list `Count` property in `for` loop.

Comment: I think you're alluding to the fact that you can't modify a collection while enumerating it but that's not the issue here.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. Next time I will read carefully

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the code, it strikes me that you should not affect the input list... only return a list.. so I reckon something like this is the better solution. Altering an input parameter is not really good practice.

```
    public async Task<List<RsiModel>> RsiDrawGraph(List<ChartDataModel> allValue)
{
    return allValue.OrderDescending(l => allValue.IndexOf(l)).Select( v => new RsiModel { LowerBorder = 30, UpperBorder = 70, rsi = await Rsi(v), Time = v.Time, x=v.x }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This assumes that it isn't important that `rsi = await Rsi(allValue)` gets a decreasing collection and that reversing the order of the collection isn't important.

Comment: @HasaniH... I have modified my code.. with an idea as to how to inverse the order.. :). Not tested though.. just want to play along..